# Posts from admin panel on different subpages

Tags: python, django, html, posts

I would like to add post list from main page to another subpages. (main page to subpage called "programowanie")

For example:
I have a website   wwww.example.com. On this website I have a post list that is generated from admin panel (I can add, delete a posts using admin panel).
The problem is that when I try to copy templates from start page with post list to other subpage (called: www.example.com/programowanie) it doeasn't work (I see a template from main page but without post list)
I think the problem is in templates/blog/post/list.html in loop {% for post in posts %}
If I solve this problem I would like to add in admin panel different overlap to publish posts only in "programowanie" subpage.

This is my files:
blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, HttpResponse
from .models import Post, Posta, Comment
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from taggit.models import Tag
from django.db.models import Count


def post_share(request, post_id):
    # Pobranie posta na podstawie jego identyfikatora.
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, status='published')
    sent = False

if request.method == 'POST':
    # Formularz został wysłany.
    form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Weryfikacja pól formularza zakończyła się powodzeniem…
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(
                                      post.get_absolute_url())
        subject = '{} ({}) zachęca do przeczytania "{}"'.format(cd['nick'], cd['email'], post.title)
        message = 'Przeczytaj post "{}" na stronie {}\n\n Komentarz dodany przez {}: {}'.format(post.title, post_url, cd['nick'], cd['komentarz'])
        send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com', [cd['adresat']])
        sent = True

else:
    form = EmailPostForm()
return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
                                                'form': form,
                                                'sent': sent})

class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'

def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

if tag_slug:
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
    object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # Trzy posty na każdej stronie.
    page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    posts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # Jeżeli zmienna page nie jest liczbą całkowitą,
    # wówczas pobierana jest pierwsza strona wyników.
    posts = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # Jeżeli zmienna page ma wartość większą niż numer ostatniej strony
    # wyników, wtedy pobierana jest ostatnia strona wyników.
    posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
return render(request,
              'blog/post/list.html',
              {'page': page,
              'posts': posts,
               'tag': tag})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                               status='published',
                               publish__year=year,
                               publish__month=month,
                               publish__day=day)
comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.post = post
        new_comment.save()
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()

  # Lista podobnych postów.
post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids)\
                              .exclude(id=post.id)
similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
                             .order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]

return render(request,
              'blog/post/detail.html',
              {'post': post,
               'comments': comments,
               'comment_form': comment_form,
               'similar_posts': similar_posts})


def programowanie(request):
        return render(request, 'blog/post/base.html')
```

blog/models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
                     self).get_queryset()\
                     .filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Roboczy'),
        ('published', 'Opublikowany'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager() # Menedżer domyślny.
    published = PublishedManager() # Menedżer niestandardowy.
    tags = TaggableManager() 

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                             self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                             self.slug])

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    komentarz = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Komentarz dodany przez {} dla posta {}'.format(self.name, 
self.post)
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
# Widoki posta.
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
url(r'^programowanie/$', views.programowanie, name='programowanie'),
#url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
    r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
    views.post_detail,
    name='post_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/share/$', views.post_share,
    name='post_share'),
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_list,
    name='post_list_by_tag'),
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views

 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name="about"),
    url(r'^programowanie/', views.programowanie, name="programowanie"),
    url(r'^algorytmy/', views.algorytmy, name="algorytmy"),
    url(r'^kontakt/', views.kontakt, name="kontakt"),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls',
                           namespace='blog',
                           app_name='blog')),
]
```

blog/templates/base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% include "navbar.html" with page=posts %}
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link href="{% static "admin/css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body>
  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <h2>Mój blog</h2>
      <p>To jest mój blog.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

blog/templates/post/list.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}


{% block title %}Mój blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Mój blog</h1>
  {% if tag %}
    <h2>Posty oznaczone tagiem "{{ tag.name }}"</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="tags">
      Tagi:
      {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <a href="{% url "blog:post_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">
          {{ tag.name }}
        </a>
        {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </p>
    <p class="date">
      Opublikowany {{ post.publish }} przez {{ post.author }}
    </p>
    {{ post.body|truncatewords_html:30|linebreaks }}
  {% endfor %}

  {% include "pagination.html" with page=posts %}
{% endblock %}
```

blog/templates/post/detail.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  <p class="date">
     Opublikowany {{ post.publish }} przez {{ post.author }}
  </p>
   {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
  <p>
    <a href="{% url "blog:post_share" post.id %}">
      Udostępnij posta
    </a>
  </p>
 <h2>Podobne posty</h2>
  {% for post in similar_posts %}
    <p>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </p>
  {% empty %}
    Nie ma podobnych postów.
  {% endfor %}
{% with comments.count as total_comments %}
    <h2>
      {{ total_comments }} komentarz{{ total_comments|pluralize:"y" }}
    </h2>
  {% endwith %}

  {% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="comment">
      <p class="info">
        Komentarz {{ forloop.counter }} dodany przez {{ comment.name }}
          {{ comment.created }}
      </p>
      {{ comment.komentarz|linebreaks }}
    </div>
  {% empty %}
    <p>Nie ma jeszcze żadnych komentarzy.</p>
  {% endfor %}

  {% if new_comment %}
    <h2>Twój komentarz został dodany.</h2>
  {% else %}
    <h2>Dodaj nowy komentarz</h2>
    <form action="." method="post">
      {{ comment_form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <p><input type="submit" value="Dodaj komentarz"></p>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for any help !! (I thinking about this third day )

Comment: And stop talking about "from admin panel". As far as I can tell, the admin has nothing whatsoever to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have it's in the views.

Django template has to be rendered by a view, from this view is where you get the data to be rendered in the template. It doesn't matter which url you want to use and which template you are using in the views. What this means is that you can have different urls pointing to the same template (www.example.com/blog/ or www.example.com/programming/) and both render the same template.

If i understood you right, all you have to do is change this :

```
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
url(r'^programowanie/$', views.programowanie, name='programowanie'),
```

To this:

```
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
url(r'^programowanie/$', views.post_list, name='programowanie'),
```

You can refer to the official Django website in order to get more information about this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: I changed this lines but still the problem is. The template is rendering from main page but I don't see a post list from admin panel ( I would like to obtain the same view like main page with post list)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help :)

I solved this problem. There was a problem in urls.py file.